# How to define type of Custom Component in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a React component `Title`, which renders `h1...h6, span or div` based on the `props` passed to the component.

Works Fine: In this case, there is no `typescript` error.

```
interface ComponentProps {
    tag?: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "span" | "div";
    type: "title" | "subtitle";
    text: string;
    variation: string;
}

const Title: FC<ComponentProps> = ({tag}) => {
  let Tag = tag;
  return (
    <Tag>Text</Tag>
  )
}
```

Error Scenario: When I try to assign any element to `Tag`, it gives a `typescript` error. I'm trying to check If the `tag` prop is empty in the example below. If it is empty then assign either h1 or h2 based on the type prop.

```
const Title: FC<ComponentProps> = ({tag, type, text, variation}) => {
   let Tag = tag || '';
   if(!Tag.length){
      if(type=='title'){
         Tag = 'h1'
      } else {
         Tag = 'h2'
      }
   }
   return (
     <Tag className={variation}>{text}</Tag>
   )
}
```

Error:

> Type '{ children: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

**Note**: I can't use React.createElement.

Could anyone please help me with this.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQrwAdjElOekjiFqkTkm4AFKmADOuVnEVwYKAOYB+AFx0AFgEZacAD66ATIZO0dAZgu6ALHasBWJzoBsTmWBScnAE2AANxYFJRgATzAkbVoYYBgAGyQvAFcAI3iklLYlZSQADxhtGRgoLlVcpSCUcpR4iE4Ssoq2EnY0RtK4ABUE5O0iAB5hcEbxGCkIWQA+OABeOAAKPBVVbEjojcKsOBq6hs5SAEoFuZwwxWT4HrUF5TujS1DLuGByZYBCW9UAOmTOKoYDpThc8nl3stNoJ5os4v0UqDXuClD97lYDFUUWQkIkZIIwSjwWi4TpzFjwe08lSlK8GDBUlAjkM0WhEigZDIAHIoEBIeY4fbAerARokGY4HhFEhDAD0PxmbTYQA)

Comment: Can't reproduce? I get no error with your code. Please create a codesandbox or something the shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tag` can be optional and you'll be assigning it a new value anyways, there is no need to default to `""` right away. You can just set `Tag` to `tag` and then check if `Tag` is undefined (here I'm just using `!Tag` for simplicity):

```
const Title: FC<ComponentProps> = ({ tag, type, text, variation }) => {
    let Tag = tag;

    if (!Tag) {
        if (type == "title") {
            Tag = "h1";
        } else {
            Tag = "h2";
        }
    }
    
    return <Tag className={variation}>{text}</Tag>;
};
```

Now the type of `Tag` is `"h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "span" | "div" | undefined`, but TypeScript is smart enough to see that when you use `Tag` in the `return`, it's no longer `undefined` since you change it to `"h1"` or `"h2"` if it is. Previously, the type of `Tag` was inferred as `string` because of the empty string.

Therefore, another way you *could* fix it (but you shouldn't do it this way) would be:

```
const Title: FC<ComponentProps> = ({ tag, type, text, variation }) => {
    let Tag = tag || "" as ""; // tag ?? "" as "" also works

    if (!Tag) { // Tag === "" also works
        if (type == "title") {
            Tag = "h1";
        } else {
            Tag = "h2";
        }
    }

    return <Tag className={variation}>{text}</Tag>;
};
```

[Playground (`let Tag = tag;`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQrwAdjElOekjiFqkTkm4AFKmADOuVnEVwYKAOYB+AFx0AFgEZacAD66ATIZO0dAZgu6ALHasBWJzoBsTmWBScnAE2AANxYFJRgATzAkbVoYYBgAGyQvAFcAI3iklLYlZSQADxhtGRgoLlVcpSCUcpR4iE4Ssoq2EnY0RtK4ABUE5O0iAB5hcEbxGCkIWQA+OABeOAAKPBVVbEjojcKsOBq6hs5SAEoFuZwwxWT4HrUF5TU2S7hgcmWAQlvVU4u8vNflptBPNFnF+ikfs8-kovvcrAYqtCyEhEjJBL9oX9YaCdOZEX92nlCUpngwYKkoEchrC0IkUDIZAA5FAgJDzHD7YD1YCNEgzHA8IokIYAei+MzabCAA)

[Playground (`let Tag = tag || "" as "";`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQrwAdjElOekjiFqkTkm4AFKmADOuVnEVwYKAOYB+AFx0AFgEZacAD66ATIZO0dAZgu6ALHasBWJzoBsTmWBScnAE2AANxYFJRgATzAkbVoYYBgAGyQvAFcAI3iklLYlZSQADxhtGRgoLlVcpSCUcpR4iE4Ssoq2EnY0RtK4ABUE5O0iAB5hcEbxGCkIWQA+OABeOAAKPBVVbEjojcKsOBq6hs5SAEoFuZwwxWT4HrUF5TujS0MUOVpQy7hgcmWAQlvVKcLnk8t9lptBPNFnF+ikgZ8QUoAfcrAYqoiyEhEjJBMDESDkdCdOZ0SD2nlyUpPgwYKkoEchsi0IlXjIAHIoEBIeY4fbAerARokGY4HhFEhDAD0AJmbTYQA)

---

You should also consider inlining the if's to a ternary:

```
const Title: FC<ComponentProps> = ({ tag, type, text, variation }) => {
    // you could also use
    // let Tag: NonNullable<ComponentProps["tag"]> = ...
    // but it's quite a bit longer than this lol
    let Tag = tag ?? type === "title" ? "h1" as "h1" : "h2" as "h2";

    return <Tag className={variation}>{text}</Tag>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQrwAdjElOekjiFqkTkm4AFKmADOuVnEVwYKAOYB+AFx0AFgEZacAD66ATIZO0dAZgu6ALHasBWJzoBsTmWBScnAE2AANxYFJRgATzAkbVoYYBgAGyQvAFcAI3iklLYlZSQADxhtGRgoLlVcpSCUcpR4iE4Ssoq2EnY0RtK4ABUE5O0iAB5hcEbxGCkIWQA+OABeOAAKPBVVbEjojcKsOBq6hs5SAEoFuZwwxWT4HrUF5Tv1dWUowXn3uizkw2erAzgUHI-oZYjpzACgWDQnlLnAGDBUlAjkNbqo4GhEoCZAA5FAgJDzHD7YD1YCNEgzHA8IokIYAelRMzabCAA)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the return to following

```
return (
    {tag === h1 && (<h1 className={className}>{text}</h1>)}
)
```

(also you can delete the `if else` statements as its not necessary with this approach)

Comment: Hi, I have only mentioned 2 conditions in this example but these are nested if else condition and at the end when the tag is actually specified in that case I would have to use Tag variable as Element.

Comment: I got your point. The above-mentioned provides you with the exact same result but it is a different approach. The only condition you need is to check which type of tag is it.. and render the tag respectively. so in above example, if the tag is h1, then render the <h1> and so on..